# IIS 10 Gives Blank Screen for PHP 7.1.0 in phpinfo() page

Tags: php, iis, iis-10, php-7.1

I successfully used PHP 7.0 with IIS and was able to view the phpinfo page. When I upgraded and pointed to PHP 7.1 the phpinfo page in IIS is blank and the spinner continues to act like it is loading. I am able to successfully load php pages in the browser using 7.1 as well. Why is the phpinfo page not loading?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the logs? Any errors there?

Comment: I did and it's the same error that is always in there: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0`. I verified the path to that exists and it is valid. Regardless, I am able to load and serve other php pages just fine.

Comment: I also figured out that mysql.dll issue goes away by disabling the extensions since mysqli seems to be the preferred way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slap your head moment. PHP Storm was still listening for xdebug connections which was tripping it up. Turning that off allowed it to show up.